# java scripts deleted now what

Tags: security, hacking

i discovered that my web site has all java scripts are now deleted!!!! what should i do???

Comment: You're doing it wrong …

Answer (score 8):

Put them back, and take more care of 'em next time.

Comment: Upvote for the simplicity and fact that it brought a smile to my face :)

Answer (score 4):

Restore from the backups which you, of course, made, since you know that keeping backups is critical.

Answer (score 3):

- Hope that your hosting company does
  tape backups?
- Redeploy from your test environment
  (you do have a test environment
  right)?
- Rewrite them?